# how to start meteor app behind a corporate proxy in windows 7?

Tags: meteor, npm, proxy, windows-firewall, pac

I have a meteor app which i want to run on my local machine using webstorm IDE in my Windows 7 OS. I have navigated to the meteor project folder and then entered command `meteor run`.
The output is

```
D:\test\Dashboard>meteor run
[[[[[ ~\D\test\Dashboard ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While downloading typ:semantic-ui@0.7.3...:
   error: connect ETIMEDOUT 123.12.12.12:123

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

By looking in `network and security` setting in my windows 7, I found my corporate proxy has a URL of a proxy file.
According to [GITHUB](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Meteor-behind-a-proxy) i have tested the set methods, but i dont know what the username, password and IP should be used for that. 
 So can anyone help me to resolve this issue? or is there anyway i can configure the proxy?

Comment: This is something you will need to ask your systems administrator for help with. Nobody on SO will know the answer.

Comment: hmm..ok thanks for the suggestion.